# Microsoft Word 2007 opening all docs with field codes toggled off

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

Recently, something changed with my Microsoft Word 2007 installation/preferences on Windows XP, such that whenever I open a word document, all the field codes are displayed raw instead of as their expanded value.  For example, my header reads:

```
My Name { TITLE \* MERGEFORMAT }    Version { REVNUM \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

But, if I copy and paste it here, it reads expanded:

```
My Name My Doc Title    Version 42
```

I expect to see the copy and paste version directly inside Word, I can work around this by right clicking on each such field and choosing toggle field codes, however, I never had to do that before, as previously, the document opened with all such field codes expanded.

Another example is the Table of Contents which shows as:

```
{ TOC \o "1-3" \h \z \u }
```

Instead of the full table of contents.

I searched the word options dialog, but could not find anything that appeared relevant.

Please suggest how to restore the old behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the control in Word 2007 in the Advanced section of the options dialog under 'Show Document Content':

[image]

Comment: The setting is a bit subtle to find in Mac Office Word, but it is there.  This information may restore my sanity.

Answer (score 6):

You need to clear this checkbox.

[image]

Comment: That looks like the 2003 version, I'm running the newer 2007 version with the ribbon.  I don't find the equivalent in the new version, anyone know where it is?

Comment: Found it, see below.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in Word 2010 on Windows 7, and it was also solved the above steps. Note that at the same time I had ActiveX buttons tied to VBA macros and the buttons were converted to pictures and so no longer functioned as buttons. I have found no way to reverse this. It is possible that the two problems occurring together are evidence of some sort of corruption, since I am certain I did not change the field codes setting. Further, this problem occurred when I opened up older documents that could not have been independently corrupted.

This problem occurred after I exited Word but the process was still running and I ended up rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

And if you are working with MS Office for Mac you will find this checkbox by:

1. Word --> Preferences
2. From the first row at the top "Authoring and Proofing Tools" --> cick View
3. In the first group of options "Show" --> Untick the box: "Field codes"

That'll do the trick.